# Are there any online printing & framing "shopping cart" services based in Canada?

Tags: printing, service-recommendation, online-shopping

I am currently with Fine Art America (FAA) which has a fantastic "shopping cart" app for Facebook but not a very nice layout for online portfolios.  It does what I want it to do - allows people to very easily purchase my photos and customize their frames, size, paper, etc.

One **huge** problem I have with this and other popular photo sites that feature the convenient "shopping cart" service is that **shipping to Canada is very expensive** which increases the price of any order significantly. Consequently this is a big turn off for local buyers.

Unfortunately this is true of all printing services offered by [Smugmug](http://help.smugmug.com/customer/portal/articles/93270), [Zenfolio](http://help.zenfolio.com/customer/portal/articles/408056-ordering-prints-and-products) and other popular US based sites that cater only to US based photographers and their buyers in this particular regard. (A reason why I will be cancelling my FAA account and why I will not create a portfolio with Smugmug nor Zenfolio. (Too bad because I really like Zenfolio)

All of these printing and framing services only offer premium international shipping at astronomical prices and some also say that any customs fees are the responsibility of the person ordering the items.

I can't find any services similar to what FAA offers in Canada aside from [PosterJack](http://www.posterjack.ca/framedphotos.php) (No photographer portfolio options), [Blacks](http://www.blacks.ca) (No photographer portfolio options, only canvas and poster - no framing), etc.

Does anyone know of a "Shopping Cart" service that can do what FAA, Smugmug, Zenfolio but is based in Canada?

Answer (score 3):

I don't have any answer for your question of, what client proofing and shopping cart sites are based in Canada. What I do have is information about US based options that might still work for you depending on your needs.

### Zenfolio

I find that the Zenfolio costs to ship to Canada are actually very reasonable. Take a look at the details at the Zenfolio Mpix [page](http://www.zenfolio.com/zf/pnp/mpix.aspx):

> **Shipping to Canada:**
>
> USPS First Class is $5.30 for orders with 50 prints or less in print sizes equal to or smaller than 5x7 (delivered in 7-10 business days)
>
> FedEx Priority International shipping is $16.25 (delivered in 1-2 business days)

$5 for standard delivery and $16 for very fast delivery seems reasonable to me. Sure they do have some limitations around print size and quality that might bump you up to the next level, but if you are fulfilling a customer order, the $16 fee should easily be covered by the margin. If your customer orders 1-2 prints, print them in house for faster fulfillment anyways. This is very common even if your print lab is in the city you live in, etc.

### Pictage

Take a look at the details at the Pictage shipping [page](http://www.pictage.com/static/shipping.html):

> **Canada**
>
> Total Web Order Cost /  FedEx Ground / FedEx Priority:
>
> $0 - $24.99, $9.95, $33.95
>
> $25 - $49.99, $12.95, $36.95
>
> $50 - $149.99, $14.95, $38.95
>
> $150+, $22.95, $46.95
>
> FedEx Ground: Orders ship in 2-3 business days and arrive in 3-5
> business days FedEx Priority: Orders ship in 1-2 business days and
> arrive in 2-3 business days

So with Pictage, for $10 you can order prints, which is only $4 above US customers, and even arrives faster. For a reasonable order of $100, you are paying $15.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [FotoMoto](http://www.fotomoto.com)?  Have not used it but have heard good things.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's exactly what your looking for, but I've used Pikto several times to print my photos and they seem to do good work.  They're located in Toronto in the Distillery District.